# problem with exam document

Tags: exam

Hi I have two problems with this file. The first one is that I wish the order in each copy of the answers to question number 10 is random. The second one is that in the table with the `\{bhpword Bonus Points:}` not appear bonus points. Could you help me? thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ExamResetAfterFirstRun}{%
  \renewcommand*{\PgInfo@write}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\pointpoints{Punto}{Punti}
\bonuspointpoints{punto (bonus)}{punti (bonus)}




\begin{document}

\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{3} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi

  \begin{questions}
    \question[1]
    Why is there air?

    \question[15]
    How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could cuck
    wood?
    \bonusquestion[1] On what day of the week did he do it?
    \bonusquestion[2] What color shirt was he wearing?


    \question[10]
    Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.

    \label{ques:first}
    This is the first question.
    \question
    Page 37
    \label{ques:second}
    \begin{parts}
    \part
    \label{part:good}
    This is the good part.
    \part
    \label{part:bad}
    This is the \emph{bad} part.
    \end{parts}
    \question[10]
    Is there a question?
    \question[10] One of these things is not like the others; one of these
    things is not the same. Which one is different? 
    \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice RISPOSTA 1
    \choice Paul
    \choice George
    \choice Ringo
    \CorrectChoice Socrates
    \end{checkboxes}

   \question[10]
       Compute \fillwithlines{2in} 


    \question[20]

    \makebox[0.5in]{\hrulefill}
    out of a possible \pointsonpage{\thepage} points

    %\hrulefill

  \end{questions}

%  \gradetable[v][questions]
%  
%  
%  \begin{center}
%  \bonusgradetable[h][questions]
%  \end{center}
%  
%  \begin{center}
%  \combinedgradetable[h][questions]
%  \end{center}

  \begin{center}
   \hqword{Ex}
   \hpword{Points}
   \bhpword{Bonus Points:}
   \htword{\textbf{Total}}
   \hsword{Score}
   \cellwidth{2.2em}
   \gradetable[h][questions]
   \end{center}
   \begin{center}
   \end{center} 

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code fragment in your running text is wrong, but I marked it as `code`.

Comment: Could you clarify your two examples please? It is a little difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The first problem regards the order of the answer of the question number 10. When I compile I can see 3 copy of the document. And for example i would like that in one copy the order of the choice is: RISPOSTA 1, Paul, George, Ringo. In the second one is Paul, RISPOSTA 1, Ringo, George (I would like that the order of the choice is random every time I compile my document)

For the second one I add a similar table from examdocument.pdf

Comment: You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.